# AspNet Boilerplate "Application is shutting down..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

We are working with a client project that uses AspNet Boilerplate framework.
There is an odd behavior there, where if the app is started in debug mode, it outputs the text "Application is shutting down..." and then closes the app.

Running without debugging does not cause this.
We can pinpoint it to Abp as if we remove `.UseAbp`, the message goes away (while the app ofc no longer works)

Our issue is that we cannot find any way to pinpoint this in more detail.

Are there any known causes for this issue?
Is there anything we can do to get some form of verbose output on e.g. failed dependencies or similar?

Very vague question, I know.

Comment: Never used Boilerplate, but perhaps switch log level to `Verbose` on the Program class?

Comment: I would analyze any `#If Debug` statement and check any configuration in the launch profiles. also, any logs or stack traces would be helpful you know.